# ... This is random, right?

Tags: regression, logistic, mathematical-statistics, prediction, scatterplot

The X and Y axis are predictor variables, and the response is 1 (the + sign) or 0 (the circles).  I shouldn't explore this further, right?  There's no way to predict for 1's?
[image]

Comment: In statistics everything is "random". Yes, the plot looks pretty helpless, but you would give us more details on what is your data so that we can tell anything more.